# GridBagLayout - JFormattedTextFields are too little?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, user-interface, gridbaglayout

I am coding a gui in SWING:

```
    JLabel tLabel1 = new JLabel("Name: ");
    JFormattedTextField tTextField1 = new JFormattedTextField();
    textBoxes.add(tTextField1);
    JLabel tLabel2 = new JLabel("Maximaler Preis: ");
    JFormattedTextField tTextField2 = new JFormattedTextField();
    textBoxes.add(tTextField2);

        GridBagLayout tLayout = new GridBagLayout();
        mainFrame.getContentPane().setLayout(tLayout);
//      tLayout).setAutoCreateGaps(true);
//      tLayout.setAutoCreateContainerGaps(true);

        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;

        mainFrame.add(new JLabel("Geben sie bitte die Kriterien für die Suche an:"), gbc);

        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        gbc.gridy++;
        mainFrame.add(tLabel1, gbc);
        gbc.gridy++;
        mainFrame.add(tLabel2, gbc);
        gbc.gridy++;
        mainFrame.add(tLabel3, gbc);
        gbc.gridy++;
        mainFrame.add(tLabel4, gbc);

        gbc.gridx++;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        mainFrame.add(tTextField1, gbc);
        gbc.gridy++;
        mainFrame.add(tTextField2, gbc);
        gbc.gridy++;
        mainFrame.add(tTextField3, gbc);    
        gbc.gridy++;
        mainFrame.add(tCombo, gbc);
        gbc.gridy++;
        mainFrame.add(searchButton, gbc);

        gbc.gridy++;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;

        mainFrame.add(tTable, gbc); 
        mainFrame.setSize(800, 500);
        mainFrame.pack();
```

My text field look like that:

> |

How to give them a width in the GridBagLayout?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [`JTextField.setColumns(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html#setColumns%28int%29).

Comment: This will give the fields a fixed width - they won't stretch and shrink as the container is resized.  If this is important to you then you should set weights as well.

Comment: @Ian Excellent point Ian.  I like to suggest size based on the 'smarts' of the component itself, but the size is ultimately ruled by the layout, and (the much maligned) GBL is a powerful and adaptable layout manager that can take the preferred size as a hint when it calculates the size to make a field.  Supplying a suitable `GridBagConstraints` is the way to describe to GBL how a field or control should ideally appear, be located and be **expanded/contracted for the available space.**

Answer (score 3):

You have several options here:

1. Set the columns property of the JFormattedTextField (this will eventually influence the preferred size of the textfield)
2. Change the GridBagConstraint by

   - Setting the weightx attribute to something bigger than 0
   - Setting the fill attribute to `HORIZONTAL`

Answer (score 3):

You need to assign them a *weight* in the constraints. The weight determines how the left-over space is distributed, if you don't set weights on any components then they will all get their minimum sizes and the spare space will go outside the layout entirely.

Comment: +1 for covering another vital aspect of the combination of a component, a layout and the available space.